# Inserting into the front of a linkedlist

Tags: c++

I am having troubles with my code. the calling linkedlist does not seem to get "updated" with the values or they are not saved or something. Could use some help, Thanks.

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert_front(const T& x)
{
LinkedList* p = this;
LinkedList* tmp = new LinkedList(x,p); 
p = tmp;
cout<<p->m_data<<endl;
cout<<tmp->m_data<<endl;
```

The calling function is

```
//TEST : Inserting 10 numbers to a
cout << endl << "TEST : Inserting 10 numbers to A" << endl;
for (int k=0; k<10; k++){
A.insert_front(k+1);
} 
cout << A << endl;
cout << "Size of a = " << A.size() << endl;
```

I get an output of 1122334455667788991010
which is the tmp data value and the p data value each call
The values go to the code, and they are the right values, just when I go to print A nothing is shown just an empty list. Thanks, I'm new here but love the community.

Comment: Your concept of linked lists is flawed. A linked list has a head *pointer*, which points to the head *node*. as-written you allocate a new node, having it point its `next` to `this`, then promptly leak that allocation. In the end you have a bunch of leaked memory and a head-node that points to nothing and has what is had to begin with: an indeterminate value and a `next` pointer that goes nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your design of the linked list and of the method are wrong.

In the method you defined local variable p and assigned to it tmp. After exiting the method this local variable will be destroyed. So nothing was occured with the list itself. Neither its data member was changed. Also there is a memory leak.

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert_front(const T& x)
{
LinkedList* p = this;
LinkedList* tmp = new LinkedList(x,p); 
p = tmp;
cout<<p->m_data<<endl;
cout<<tmp->m_data<<endl;
```

You should split you class into two classes. The first one will define the node of the list and the second one will control operations withy the list and contain the head of the list as its data member.